# Email text is appearing as different colors

Tags: css, email, colors

The colors are all white in Outlook, but Gmail on mobile is showing as black and white text for the address.

I tried adding `color: #ffffff;` to `td` and `table`. I tried adding `span` for each part of the address, in case `<sup>th</sup` was causing the issue. I'm not sure what else I could try.

[image]

```
<tr>
    <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#658ead">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="10" align="center" border="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="middle"><span style="font:bold 125% Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#ffffff; letter-spacing:1.5px; line-height: 150%;">Thursday, November 30<sup>th</sup> <br />1:00 pm</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="middle" style="color: #ffffff;"><span style="font:normal 125% Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#ffffff; letter-spacing:1.5px; line-height: 150%;">2728 North 68 Street, Suite 1 <br />Scottsdale, AZ</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="middle"><span style="font:bold 100% Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#ffffff; letter-spacing:1.5px; line-height: 150%;">Seating is limited </span><br /><span style="font:normal 100% Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#ffffff; letter-spacing:1.5px; line-height: 150%;">Kindly respond by November 29<sup>th</sup></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#658ead">
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5" align="center" border="0" style=" border: 1px solid #ffffff; background:#ffffff;">
                        <tr>
                            <td bgcolor="#ffffff"><a href="mailto:Crystal.Fritz@kravet.com?subject=RSVP to Livable Luxury - Arizona on November 30th" style="font:normal 75% Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#658ead; background:#ffffff; line-height:21px; padding: 10px; letter-spacing:1px;">CLICK HERE TO RSVP</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="middle"><span style="font:italic 85% Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#ffffff; letter-spacing:1.5px; line-height: 150%;">Refreshments will be served</span></td>
            </tr>
    </table>
</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's rendering that part of the address as a clickable link, so you'll need some CSS to override link styles in the footer. Perhaps add a class and declare it in a `<style>` block in the header:

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .footerLink a {
    color: #fff !important;
  }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<td class="footerLink" align="center" valign="middle" style="color: #ffffff;"><span style="font:normal 125% Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#ffffff; letter-spacing:1.5px; line-height: 150%;">2728 North 68 Street, Suite 1 <br />Scottsdale, AZ</span></td>
```

Comment: It had to be the simplest answer: classes, lol. Thanks, delinear!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried :

color :white; thats the default in outlook

example from outlook :

```
<p class=MsoNormal><span lang=EN-GB style='color:white;mso-themecolor:background1'>Sdvsds
s <o:p></o:p></span></p>
```

Comment: try adding color: white !important , or color:white in the table body as appose to each item as well, outlook is a bit of a trickster , the best thing to do is create the form and import the HTML into outlook see how it looks there, then export the result out with the changes